# How Python's "Changed in version" statements are generated?

Tags: python, documentation, documentation-generation, code-documentation

I'm curios how the "Changed in version" statements are generated in Python's docs.

Consider the documentation for [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
Changed in version 3.1: Added support for rename.

Changed in version 3.6: The verbose and rename parameters became keyword-only arguments.

Changed in version 3.6: Added the module parameter.

Changed in version 3.7: Removed the verbose parameter and the _source attribute.

Changed in version 3.7: Added the defaults parameter and the _field_defaults attribute.
```

Where does it come from?

Comment: Quick check in the python repository would learn that is probably derived from https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Doc/library/collections.rst (and as it looks like it is in a non generated file it is most likely hard coded).